# Run Spring Boot application from child module

Tags: java, spring, gradle, spring-boot, multi-module

Assuming my multi module gradle project structure looks like this:

```
MainModule
    |
    + application 
    |
    + ... (other modules)
```

The application module contains a class annotated with @SpringBootApplication and when I'm in this directory (**MainModule/application)** I can run

> gradle bootRun  (at  MainModule/application)

and the application is working fine.

But now i want to be able to start the application with gradle from the parent directory **(MultiModule)**. How can I do this? I would like to achieve the same result using

> gradle bootRun  (at  MainModule)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Gradle you can address tasks by using a path expression:

```
gradle application:bootRun
```